# Shiny HTML text output

Tags: html, r, twitter-bootstrap, shiny

Ive been looking ages for this and I couldnt find an answer so i had to come to stackoverflow.

The problem im having today is I want to embed some shiny output into an HTML bootstrap web app.

I want the shiny numbers to display in the profit "box" if that makes sense. So some sums and made from R I want them to display those values in that HTML.

[image]

This is the HTML im using, as you can see im using the div with shiny-text-output class. Using R as the back end framework for computing values and stats.

```
<div class="info-box-content">
  <span class="info-box-text">PROFIT</span>
  <span class="info-box-number">
    <small>$</small>
    <div id="netprofit" class="shiny-text-output"></div>
  </span>
</div>
```

And this is the server.R:

```
shinyServer(function(input, output) {

    output$netprofit <- renderText({
        netText <- as.character(netprofit)
        return(netText)
    })

})
```

Comment: Are you trying to recreate what [`shinydashboard`](https://rstudio.github.io/shinydashboard/) does? i.e., it uses a bootstrap page and gives you info-bxes and value-boxes.

Comment: No. Its not a shiny dashboard. Its a normal HTML document. Just want to try and embed the results of R into an HTML.

Comment: So are you wanting an HTML document to be responsive to changing values that are calculatd through R, but not using shiny?

Comment: Yes I am using shiny, but the values are not display in the standard shiny app. They are rendered into the HTML bootstrap template. But yes I am loading shiny library and using shinyServer in the server.R file

Comment: Can you be more specific on how your UI and R communicate? You are not using the plain HTML in the ShinyUI, are you? Is it possible to provide a working example?